# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Christianity's [2nd moderator election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: David Stratton]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4582121628762112/0).

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new Hulk overlords. @DavidStratton.

Comment: I'm green with envy but so are you. (-;

Answer (score 16):

I think I speak for the majority of users here that we are excited to have David Stratton join our already stellar team of moderators.

We know you will be fair. We know you will do right by the current users. We know you will regularly encourage new users to continue on the site. We know you will knock this out of the park!

We are all excited to have you as one of our moderators.

## Congratulations!

Comment: Ditto, and don't think you're off the hook for the next election, my good friend!  I'm personally very, very glad you're here!

Comment: Thank you.  You're right, the existing mods have been stellar. Just getting this site to graduate was quite a feat.  It gives a lot to live up to, and I hope I do as well as everyone thinks I will.  Also, like Affable, I'm glad you're back and actively participating, too.

Comment: Heartily agreed - Congratulations David!

Comment: As a new moderator, Mr. David Stratton, how often are you planning on visiting this site?

Comment: @HandofDon David will not be notified of your comment. You need to put `@davidstratton` in the comment. [Read David's answers.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3746/3961) I have personally noticed that David visits the site daily.

Comment: @HandofDon -  I visit the site daily, several times.  I'm most active between 7 PM and midnight, Central Standard Time but do pop in during other times as well. I pop in as often as my work and family demands allow.  :-)

Comment: @DavidStratton Grats! I'm glad I didn't enter now! ... The **swarm** of votes I was sure to receive would have cheated the community out of a great new moderator!

Answer (score 11):

I would like to [register a complaint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu3Tv.jpg) in regard to our newest moderator. It's only been one day and already the force has been disturbed. I logged into the site this morning after putting the coffee on and pulled up the flag queue to clean up anything that had accrued overnight. As I am a few hours ahead of the other mods I usually catch most of the flags raised by the community in the evening browsing hours.

Today there were none.

My first thought was the new moderator had handled them all. This was a problem I had anticipated and having seen the communities choice in <strike>green monsters</strike> moderators I was braced for it. On closer inspection however I have to say the problem lies in another quarter.

The flags weren't all handled. Nobody raised any!

My best guess is that the plebeians are intimidated by their new green overlord. Perhaps the bad guys are also scared into unwilling cooperation with our site guidelines by his mere presence on the roster. Perhaps even the good guys are hesitant to raise flags for fear of drawing attention to themselves.

Whatever the reasons, it can't go on like this. These posts still apply:

- [Who failed to fly a flag?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3655/30)
- [Please flag us down!](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1364/30)

So here's my suggestion. We can't break in a  monster if we have no corpus of flags with which to train him¹. If intimidation is a factor, know that you won't have to face the monster alone. If something gets out of hand, just eject him to the mod room and let him take it out on us.

P.S. Congratulations David Statton, and welcome to the mod crew. It's good to have you on board.

¹ <sub>Also I need something to go with my morning coffee!</sub>

Comment: Hilarious! thanks for the lols

Comment: I think there's been a slight decrease in flag worthy posts recently. If you'd like to haze our new mod I'm quite happy to go on a flagging spree through the early years of this site!

Comment: @curiousdanni the comments there certainly need it.

Answer (score 10):

David, you have already shown you're not only ready but eager to take your place among the excellent moderators on Christianity Stack Exchange. Your consistent welcoming of new visitors, and referring them to various helps is inspirational to me among others. Congratulations on your new position, and thank you for your dedication to the site.

Answer (score 3):

David...I have learned a lot from you in the short time I've been a part of this community. Thanks for all the hard work!